# R2DBC - MssqlNonTransientException causing onErrorDropped

Tags: spring-data-r2dbc, r2dbc

I am quite fresh in reactive world and recently come across quite odd problem, context:

- using spring data with R2DBC, on MS SQL
- running on SB 2.3, OpenJDK 14 (dependencies below)
- using transactional via annotations
- using "repositories" built purely on `DatabaseClient` (code sample below)

and while trying to execute:

- delete from `master.abc.DEF`, followed by
- an invalid, on purpose, insert I get following exception:

```
2020-06-04 00:46:16.345 ERROR [....] 56223 --- [actor-tcp-nio-2] reactor.core.publisher.Operators         : Operator called default onErrorDropped

io.r2dbc.mssql.ExceptionFactory$MssqlNonTransientException: Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'some_id', table 'master.abc.DEF'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT fails.
    at io.r2dbc.mssql.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:152)
    Suppressed: reactor.core.publisher.FluxOnAssembly$OnAssemblyException: 
Assembly trace from producer [reactor.core.publisher.FluxLift] :
    reactor.core.publisher.Flux.doOnComplete
    io.r2dbc.mssql.RpcQueryMessageFlow.exchange(RpcQueryMessageFlow.java:154)
Error has been observed at the following site(s):
    |_  Flux.doOnComplete ⇢ at io.r2dbc.mssql.RpcQueryMessageFlow.exchange(RpcQueryMessageFlow.java:154)
    |_        Flux.filter ⇢ at io.r2dbc.mssql.RpcQueryMessageFlow.exchange(RpcQueryMessageFlow.java:160)
    |_    Flux.doOnCancel ⇢ at io.r2dbc.mssql.RpcQueryMessageFlow.exchange(RpcQueryMessageFlow.java:161)
    |_ Flux.doOnSubscribe ⇢ at io.r2dbc.mssql.RpcQueryMessageFlow.exchange(RpcQueryMessageFlow.java:163)
Stack trace:
        at io.r2dbc.mssql.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:152)
        at io.r2dbc.mssql.ExceptionFactory.createException(ExceptionFactory.java:181)
        at io.r2dbc.mssql.RpcQueryMessageFlow.lambda$exchange$1(RpcQueryMessageFlow.java:148)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandle$HandleSubscriber.onNext(FluxHandle.java:96)
        at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.drain(EmitterProcessor.java:426)
        at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.onNext(EmitterProcessor.java:268)
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onNext(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:90)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:203)
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onNext(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:90)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:203)
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onNext(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:90)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:203)
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onNext(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:90)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxHandleFuseable$HandleFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxHandleFuseable.java:178)
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onNext(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:90)
        at reactor.core.publisher.MonoFlatMapMany$FlatMapManyInner.onNext(MonoFlatMapMany.java:242)
        at org.springframework.cloud.sleuth.instrument.reactor.ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.onNext(ScopePassingSpanSubscriber.java:90)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeek$PeekSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeek.java:192)
        at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.drain(EmitterProcessor.java:426)
        at reactor.core.publisher.EmitterProcessor.onNext(EmitterProcessor.java:268)
        at io.r2dbc.mssql.client.ReactorNettyClient$1.next(ReactorNettyClient.java:237)
        at io.r2dbc.mssql.client.ReactorNettyClient$1.next(ReactorNettyClient.java:197)
        at io.r2dbc.mssql.message.token.Tabular$TabularDecoder.decode(Tabular.java:425)
        at io.r2dbc.mssql.client.ConnectionState$4$1.decode(ConnectionState.java:206)
        at io.r2dbc.mssql.client.StreamDecoder.withState(StreamDecoder.java:137)
        at io.r2dbc.mssql.client.StreamDecoder.decode(StreamDecoder.java:109)
        at io.r2dbc.mssql.client.ReactorNettyClient.lambda$new$6(ReactorNettyClient.java:247)
        at reactor.core.publisher.FluxPeekFuseable$PeekFuseableSubscriber.onNext(FluxPeekFuseable.java:189)
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.drainReceiver(FluxReceive.java:220)
        at reactor.netty.channel.FluxReceive.onInboundNext(FluxReceive.java:354)
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperations.onInboundNext(ChannelOperations.java:352)
        at reactor.netty.channel.ChannelOperationsHandler.channelRead(ChannelOperationsHandler.java:96)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.channelRead(ChannelInboundHandlerAdapter.java:93)
        at io.r2dbc.mssql.client.ssl.TdsSslHandler.channelRead(TdsSslHandler.java:402)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.fireChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:357)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline$HeadContext.channelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:1410)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:379)
        at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannelHandlerContext.invokeChannelRead(AbstractChannelHandlerContext.java:365)
        at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPipeline.fireChannelRead(DefaultChannelPipeline.java:919)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.AbstractNioByteChannel$NioByteUnsafe.read(AbstractNioByteChannel.java:163)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKey(NioEventLoop.java:714)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeysOptimized(NioEventLoop.java:650)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.processSelectedKeys(NioEventLoop.java:576)
        at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:493)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$4.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:989)
        at io.netty.util.internal.ThreadExecutorMap$2.run(ThreadExecutorMap.java:74)
        at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832)
```

and due to that - transaction is not rollbacked and underlying table is locked :/

The flow (simplified) is:

```
@Transactional
public Mono<X> replaceX(final String someX)
     return someRepository.deleteByX(someX)
            .then(...making a webClient-based-call)
            .flatMap(input -> someRepository.create(detailsFrom(input)))
            ....
```

Adding `Hooks.onErrorDropped(error -> ...` in a way solves the problem, but that does not seem as a proper solution and I am still wondering what could be the actual root cause - I assume my code/approach rather then r2dbc.

pom snippet

```
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.0.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
    </parent>
...

        <java.version>14</java.version>
        <!-- dependencies version -->
        <spring-sleuth.version>2.2.2.RELEASE</spring-sleuth.version>
        <reactor-tools.version>3.3.5.RELEASE</reactor-tools.version>
        <reactor-tools-blockhound.version>1.0.3.RELEASE</reactor-tools-blockhound.version>
        <mssql-jdbc.version>7.4.1.jre11</mssql-jdbc.version> <!-- override spring's default -->
        <hibernate-validator.version>6.1.5.Final</hibernate-validator.version>
        <springdoc-webflux.version>1.3.2</springdoc-webflux.version>
        <logstash-logback.version>6.3</logstash-logback.version>
...

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-r2dbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.h2database</groupId>
            <artifactId>h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>r2dbc-h2</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.sqlserver</groupId>
            <artifactId>mssql-jdbc</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.r2dbc</groupId>
            <artifactId>r2dbc-mssql</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
```

repository methods (conceptual):

```
    public Mono<Void> deleteByX(final String x) {
        return this.databaseClient.delete()
            .from(X.class)
            .matching(where("x").is(x))
            .then();
    }

    public Mono<Long> create(final @NonNull X x) {
        return this.databaseClient.insert()
            .into(X.class)
            .using(x)
            .map(row -> row.get(0, Long.class))
            .first();
    }
```

Comment: This issue looks like a bug. I filed https://github.com/r2dbc/r2dbc-mssql/issues/162.